# Better way to store password during oozie spark job workflow

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I have an oozie workflow which executes a spark job, which needs usernames and passwords to connect to various servers. Right now I pass it in the workflow.xml as arguments:
username
password

It's (of course) a bad way to do this as it makes the password visible. What is the standard way to obfuscate the password in such a case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Sqoop** is an interesting case, as you can see in its [documentation](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server):

- at first there was just the `--password` command-line option, followed by the password in plain text (yuck!)
- then the `--password-file` was introduced, followed by a file that contains the password; it's a clear improvement because
  *(a)* when running on an Edge Node, the password itself is not visible to anyone running a `ps` command
  *(b)* when running in Oozie, you can just upload the file once in HDFS, then tell Oozie to download it to the CWD of the YARN container running your job, with a `<file>` option, and the password itself is not visible to anyone who inspects the job definition
   *---- but don't you forget to restrict access to the damn file, both on Edge Node and on HDFS, otherwise the password could still be compromised ----*
- finally, an optional Credential Store was introduced in Hadoop, and Sqoop supports that natively *(although you now have the issue of protecting the password you use to connect to the Credential Store...)*

Similarly, for **Spark** (and also for any custom Java / Scala / Python app) I strongly suggest that you store all sensitive information in a "properties" file, restrict access to that file, then pass it as a command-line argument to your program.

It will also make your life easier if you have distinct Dev / Test / Prod environments -- the Oozie script and "properties" filename will be exactly the same, but the actual props will be environment-specific.